# Rotate a view like a knob

Tags: android, math, android-custom-view

I have to modify some one's project .  `getTheta` is a method in that project which i didn't understand but it `help to rotate view rotate like a knob (not fully 360 but less on b/s)`

```
 private float getTheta(float x, float y)
    {
        float sx = x - (float)getWidth() / 2.0F;
        float sy = y - (float)getHeight() / 2.0F;

        float length = (float)Math.sqrt(sx * sx + sy * sy);

        float nx = sx / length;

        float theta = 57.29578F * (float)Math.atan2(sy / length, nx);

        if (theta < 0.0F)
        {
            theta += 360F;
        }
        return theta;
    }
```

What i find method of getting theta is

```
private float getMyTheta(float x, float y) {
    float sx = x - (getWidth() / 2.0f);
    float sy = y - (getHeight() / 2.0f);

    float length = (float) Math.sqrt(sx * sx + sy * sy);
    float nx = sx / length;
    float ny = sy / length;

    float theta = (float) Math.atan2(ny, nx);

    final float rad2deg = (float) (180.0 / Math.PI);

    float theta2 = theta * rad2deg;

    return (theta2 < 0) ? theta2 + 360.0f : theta2;
}
```

Can someone explain me what is doing in `getTheta(float x,float y);`

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: both methods do the same thing, apparently. (get the angle of a point in polar coordinates, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system)

Comment: The first method is a little weird, since dividing both x and y by length is unnecessary if all you're going to do with them is pass them to atan. And they use the magic constant 57.29 instead of something more self-documenting like `360 / (2*math.pi)`. Otherwise, it looks like these methods do the same thing.

Comment: @Kevin `something more self-documenting` but more cumputationally hungry (one multiplication and a division). I'd put the documented expression in a comment to inform about the magical constant. But still prefer using the precalculated value.

Comment: `x` coordinate becomes the base of a right triangle, `y` coordinate becomes the height of a right triangle.  `Tan(theta) = y/x` likewise `theta = ArcTan(y/x) `